# Sharepoint 2010 Upload Document page customization

Tags: 2010, page-layout, file-upload

How can I change the text on Upload Document page from "Destination Folder" to "Project Folder"?

Comment: Some questions: first, what should be the scope of the change? Whole web site or a single document library? Second, can you provide a screen of the label yoy need to change? Maybe it's just my misundertanding, but I don't see that label on the upload form.

Answer (score 1):

The upload document page resides under the layouts directory with filename "Upload.aspx".

If you're on on-prem environment where you're allowed to do little customization:

- Create a copy of "Upload.aspx" and edit the html (Change text)
- Create a Custom Action for the ribbon to replace the out of the box Upload Document button with yours that would open your customized upload page
- Modify the functionality of  (+) Add document link so that it opens your custom upload page.

An alternative and easy approach would be to modify the text using javascript/jQuery. You can add this snippet to your custom javascript file referenced in your master page. If languages other than English are being used, you need to modify the script accordingly.

```
function changeHeaderText() {
  if (document.URL.toLowerCase().indexOf('/upload.aspx') != -1) {
      // Check if header with text exist
      $("h3.ms-standardheader:contains('Destination Folder')").text("Project Folder");
  }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    changeHeaderText();
});
```